# Cannot show the "body" response on Json, only the full response on Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to advance on a project, and my only doubt is:
how can I access the first array's response if all the arrays have the same attribute names, body, etc?
like this: [console.log and screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxYpA.png)

on a simple json server all works fine.

I need to list the batches in this array to show the results in this screen:

I've tried almost everything, but no result;

- Search by index function;
- Search the array by filter function;
- Map function the array.

But maybe am I doing all this wrong?
here's the service to fech:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LotesService implements OnInit{

  readonly apiURL = `http://localhost:3000`;
  readonly lotesURL = 'item';
  readonly registrosURL = 'registros';

  readonly termId = '?id=';
  readonly mode = mode.CONTINUABLE;
  readonly size = 2000;
  readonly elements = 2000;
  readonly continuable = 'ODEwODE3ODQwMDMwMTIyMDQ3';
  readonly selector = Selector;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }
  
  //Function to Fetch Batches on Lotes API - Listar Lotes
  getLotes(situacao: situacao.ATIVO){
    let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('situacao', situacao);
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.apiURL}/${this.lotesURL}/`,{params: params});
  }

export enum situacao {
  ATIVO = "ATIVO",
  INATIVO = "INATIVO",
  REMOVIDO = "REMOVIDO",
}
```

and here's the batch component:

```
import { Lote, situacao} from 'src/app/services/lotes.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/services/header-service.service';
import { LotesService } from 'src/app/services/lotes.service';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lotes',
  templateUrl: './lotes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lotes.component.css'],
})

//status 200 sempre
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LotesComponent implements OnInit {
  //onde irá ser gerada a array dos lotes e
  //configuração das colunas da tabela que irá ser mostrada
  MostrarColunas: string[] = ['id', 'dataProcessamento', 'quantidadeClientes', "quantidadeParcelas", "situacao"];
  lotes: Lote[] = [];
  dataSource = this.lotes;

  public pageslice = this.lotes.slice(0, 5);
  
  //paginação
  pageSize = 3;
  pageIndex = 0;
  pageSizeOptions = [3, 6, 9];
  showFirstLastButtons = true;
  handlePageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
    const startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
    let endIndex = startIndex + event.pageSize;
    if (endIndex > this.lotes.length) {
      endIndex = this.lotes.length;
    }
    this.pageslice = this.lotes.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
  }

  constructor(private loteService: LotesService,
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      this.lotes = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerService.setTitle('Lotes');
    this.BuscaLotes();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  
  BuscaLotes() {
    this.loteService.getLotes(situacao.ATIVO).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lotes = data;
        console.log(this.lotes);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

my object:

```
export class Lote {
  constructor(
    public id: any,
    public dataProcessamento: Date | "dd/MM/yyyy",
    public quantidadeClientes: number,
    public quantidadeParcelas: number,
    public situacao: situacao
    ) {}
}
```

My question is: How can I Access the Json data to display just the body attribute?

json data:

```
"item": [
        {
            "name": "lotes - Listar lotes",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "{{HOST}}"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "assessorias",
                        "lotes"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "sort",
                            "value": "situacao",
                            "description": "Ordenação",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "0",
                            "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "size",
                            "value": "50",
                            "description": "Tamanho da página",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "situacao",
                            "value": "ATIVO",
                            "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]",
                            "disabled": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": [
                {
                    "name": "lotes - *",
                    "originalRequest": {
                        "method": "GET",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Authorization",
                                "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "name": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ],
                        "url": {
                            "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes",
                            "protocol": "https",
                            "host": [
                                "{{HOST}}"
                            ],
                            "path": [
                                "api",
                                "assessorias",
                                "lotes"
                            ],
                            "query": [
                                {
                                    "key": "sort",
                                    "value": "situacao",
                                    "description": "Ordenação",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "page",
                                    "value": "0",
                                    "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "size",
                                    "value": "50",
                                    "description": "Tamanho da página",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "situacao",
                                    "value": "ATIVO",
                                    "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]",
                                    "disabled": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "status": "OK",
                    "code": 200,
                    "_postman_previewlanguage": "json",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Date",
                            "value": "Fri, 07 May 2021 19:01:18 GMT"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Length",
                            "value": "219"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Connection",
                            "value": "keep-alive"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Encoding",
                            "value": "gzip"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Expires",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-next",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-count",
                            "value": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-size",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
                            "value": "1; mode=block"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Pragma",
                            "value": "no-cache"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "350"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "999"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                            "value": "DENY"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-previous",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "349"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "15000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                            "value": "nosniff"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-pages",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-number-elements",
                            "value": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "9"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cookie": [],
                    "body": "[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081673531130966016\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-27\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"0\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"0\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081682225134571520\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-28\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1576\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35500\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083447097597952000\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-29\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083450368450428928\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-30\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083817674049376256\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-05-01\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"ATIVO\"\n    }\n]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "lotes - Ativos",
                    "originalRequest": {
                        "method": "GET",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Authorization",
                                "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "name": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ],
                        "url": {
                            "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes?situacao=ATIVO",
                            "protocol": "https",
                            "host": [
                                "{{HOST}}"
                            ],
                            "path": [
                                "api",
                                "assessorias",
                                "lotes"
                            ],
                            "query": [
                                {
                                    "key": "sort",
                                    "value": "situacao",
                                    "description": "Ordenação",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "page",
                                    "value": "0",
                                    "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "size",
                                    "value": "50",
                                    "description": "Tamanho da página",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "situacao",
                                    "value": "ATIVO",
                                    "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "status": "OK",
                    "code": 200,
                    "_postman_previewlanguage": "json",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Date",
                            "value": "Wed, 28 Apr 2021 22:22:09 GMT"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Length",
                            "value": "134"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Connection",
                            "value": "keep-alive"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Encoding",
                            "value": "gzip"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Expires",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-next",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-count",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-size",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
                            "value": "1; mode=block"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Pragma",
                            "value": "no-cache"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "350"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                            "value": "DENY"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-previous",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "349"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "15000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                            "value": "nosniff"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-pages",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-number-elements",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "9"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cookie": [],
                    "body": "[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081682225134571520\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-28\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1576\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35500\",\n        \"situacao\": \"ATIVO\"\n    }\n]"
                }
            ]
        }
```

maybe am I missing something?

thanks in advance, and take it easy! it's my first question here

Answer (score 0):

If you only were getting just 1 item, you could use **pluck**

```
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';


BuscaLotes() {
    this.loteService.getLotes(situacao.ATIVO)
    .pipe(
      pluck('body')
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lotes = data;
        console.log(this.lotes);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

However, you are receiving an array. So you have to **map** the array:

```
BuscaLotes() {
    this.loteService.getLotes(situacao.ATIVO)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lotes = data.map((lote)=>lote.body);
        console.log(this.lotes);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```